# how to find solution of equations based on bisection method

Tags: java, bisection

I'm trying to implement the bisection method for finding the solutions of an equation.

The form of the equation is like this:
 pe^(-x) + q*sin(x) + r*cos(x) + s*tan(x) + t*x^2 + u = 0 , with 0 ≤ p,r ≤ 20, -20 ≤ q,s,t ≤ 0 e -20 ≤ u ≤ 20

input example:

3
 1. 0 0 0 0 -2 1
 1 0 0 0 -1 2
1 -1 1 -1 -1 1

should give :

0.7071
Impossible
0.7554

I tried to implement this but I can't display the result with 4 decimal places, and I realized that a b and c are in the form of x.x with only one decimal place. I think the problem starts here. Any help would be very appreciated . Here's my code

```
class p07{
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n= in.nextInt();

    for (int i=0 ; i < n; i++)
        bss(in.nextInt(), in.nextInt(),in.nextInt(), in.nextInt(),in.nextInt(), in.nextInt());

}

public static void bss(int p, int q, int r, int s, int t, int u){
    double fa=0, fb=0, fc=0;

    boolean flag=true;

    double a=-20;
    double b=a;

    while(flag){

        fa=p*Math.exp(a) + q*Math.sin(a) + r*Math.cos(a) + s*Math.tan(a) + t*Math.pow(a,2) + u;
        fb=p*Math.exp(b+1) + q*Math.sin(b+1) + r*Math.cos(b+1) + s*Math.tan(b+1) + t*Math.pow(b+1,2) + u;

        a++;b++;

        if( (fa < 0 && fb > 0) || (fa > 0 && fb < 0) )
            flag=false;
    }

    System.out.println("a= "+a+", b= "+b);
    System.out.println("f(a)= "+fa+", f(b)= "+fb);

    int k=4;
    double c=0.000;

    while(k!=0){

        c = (a+b)/2;
        fa = p*Math.exp(a) + q*Math.sin(a) + r*Math.cos(a) + s*Math.tan(a) + t*Math.pow(a,2) + u;
        fc = p*Math.exp(c) + q*Math.sin(c) + r*Math.cos(c) + s*Math.tan(c) + t*Math.pow(c,2) + u;

        if( fa < fc)
            b=c;
        else
            a=c;
        k--;
        System.out.println("a= "+a+",b= "+b+", c= "+c);
    }
    double sol =p*Math.exp(c) + q*Math.sin(c) + r*Math.cos(c) + s*Math.tan(c) + t*Math.pow(c,2) + u;
    System.out.println(sol);
}
```

}

Comment: So just to be clear, you're looking for roots of the equation?  Because I think there's more than one "bisection method" in mathematics.  What's the initial interval for you to search?  I'm not clear where that is on your input.

Comment: yes @markspace the roots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some errors:

the third one doesnt converge.

- bad test: you should test if fa and fc have different signs=> if (fa*fc<0)
- you should also test if you get a root
- I simplified your first test with a break
- sol is not a solution, but f(pseudo-root)

I dont understand your problem about decimals: a,b,c are double.

I replace the loop with 10 iterations.

so, it gives:

```
double fa=0, fb=0, fc=0;

double a=-20;
double b=a+1;

while(true)
    {
    fa=p*Math.exp(a) + q*Math.sin(a) + r*Math.cos(a) + s*Math.tan(a) + t*Math.pow(a,2) + u;
    fb=p*Math.exp(b) + q*Math.sin(b) + r*Math.cos(b) + s*Math.tan(b) + t*Math.pow(b,2) + u;

    if( (fa < 0 && fb > 0) || (fa > 0 && fb < 0) )
        break;

    a++;b++;
    }

System.out.println("a= "+a+", b= "+b);
System.out.println("f(a)= "+fa+", f(b)= "+fb);

int k=10;
double c=0.0;

while(k!=0)
    {

    c = (a+b)/2;
    fa = p*Math.exp(a) + q*Math.sin(a) + r*Math.cos(a) + s*Math.tan(a) + t*Math.pow(a,2) + u;
    fc = p*Math.exp(c) + q*Math.sin(c) + r*Math.cos(c) + s*Math.tan(c) + t*Math.pow(c,2) + u;

    // ROOT
    if (fc==0) break;

    if (fa*fc<0)
        b=c;
    else
        a=c;

    k--;
    System.out.println("a= "+a+",b= "+b+", c= "+c+" f(c)"+fc);
}
double sol =p*Math.exp(c) + q*Math.sin(c) + r*Math.cos(c) + s*Math.tan(c) + t*Math.pow(c,2) + u;
System.out.println("root="+c);
```